# Graphs with Google Spreadsheets - collapse data into one 'category'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a set of data which is similar to the following:

```
Groceries     5.00
Groceries    14.75
Groceries     6.37
Dinner Out   43.50
Dinner Out   15.00
```

I'd like to be able to use this data to create some graphs, such that (in this case) I'd have two categories, and the graph displays the sum, namely `Groceries -> 26.12`, `Dinner Out -> 58.50`. etc etc.

Is this possible to do automatically, without me collapsing these rows into one sum per category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you would use a Pivot Table and in Google Spreadsheets you would need to use a Gadget. I tried it with the "Table by Google" gadget and it was straightforward though, I've used pivot tables before so it was very familiar.

Here is a [more complicated](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAbv9SSRwqU) example using a gadget I couldn't find.

Comment: Great thanks - I found it under the table section of the gadgets

Answer (score 2):

In new Google Sheets a chart can be drawn from a pivot table, no gadget necessary:

[image: WA6107 first example]

Alternatively, check Aggregate column A:

[image: WA6107 second example]